# npm: Laravel-Mix directory missing

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to run `npm run dev` on a Laravel project, but I get the following error.

> Error: Cannot find module
> '/home/faramarz/todo/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'

And yes, there is no such file in the node-module/ dir. But I ran `npm install` with no problem. I also ran `npm i laravel-mix`, but it didn't install it.

**package.json**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
}
```

}

I always face this problem running this command. Any help?

**npm -v:6.4.1**

Comment: This might sound silly sometimes. But please make sure that you've everything spelled well. I had it named as *wepack.mix.js* in my lumen project

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Delete the node_module/ directory and run the following on the command line.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
npm install webpack --save
```

Comment: @Faramarz Try running npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
if that doesn't work try running node_modules/.bin/webpack

Comment: this time the error was a bit different: `Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT`

Comment: @Faramarz I edited my answer. Try the following:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install

Answer (score 0):

Remove space and '&' from your Directory name and reinstall npm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
npm install --force --legacy-peer-deps
npm run dev
```